# skip an error row in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, error-handling, skip

I am iterating through each row in a csv file and choose/calculate only rows that meet the condition. However, when there is an error in a row, it stops the loop. is there a way to tell python to skip the error and move to the next row? I use the `try` function but did not work. my code is

```
try(row['BAS'] = float(row['Close Ask']) - float(row['Close Bid']))
```

the error is one of the cell is a string and cannot be converted into a float

Comment: [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)?

Comment: `try` is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like:

```
for row in csv_file:
    try: 
        x = float(row['Close Ask']) - float(row['Close Bid'])
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        # now keep going doing something with x
        ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can ignore the error by catching errors of that type (`ValueError`) and effectively ignoring it:

```
try:
    row['BAS'] = float(row['Close Ask']) - float(row['Close Bid'])
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

you should put your code inside a try/except:

```
try:
    code
except:
    pass
```

(you shouldn't use such broad exception catching but I don't know the error that is occuring.)

Comment: Wrong , this would skip the whole loop. Please read the question